# Как вытащить конкретный кусок из строки

Tags: c#, строки

Есть строка с именем файла(например string filename= FI_FILE1_111_1111). Как мне вытащить его префикс до второго нижнего подчеркивания(FI_FILE1_)??

Как нибудь наверное через substring и string.indexOf(но если привязаться к "_" то он возьмет только первую часть), либо через Regex

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ну например так:

```
var s = "FI_FILE1_111_1111";
var firstIndex = s.IndexOf('_');
var secondIndex = s.IndexOf('_', firstIndex + 1);
var part = s.Substring(0, secondIndex + 1);
```

При отсутствии нужного количества `_` выдаст пустую строку.

Менее эффективно, но короче:

```
var part = string.Concat(s.Split('_').Take(2).Select(p => p + "_"));
```

При отсутствии нужного количества `_` выдаст пустую строку.

Answer (score 7):

Раз уж были упомянуты регулярки:

```
string filename = "FI_FILE1_111_1111";

string pattern = "^[^_]+_[^_]+_"; // "^.+?_.+?_"

string result = Regex.Match(filename, pattern).Value;
```

Comment: А если подчеркивания идут друг за другом? надо, наверное, вместо квантификатора `+` использовать `*`?

Comment: @Андрей - я, кстати, сперва использовал `*`, потом поменял на `+`. Пусть автор вопроса решает, что ему больше подходит.

Answer (score 6):

Если важна скорость, самый быстрый вариант

```
string GetPrefix(string file)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < file.Length; i++)
    {
        if (file[i] == '_') count++;
        if (count == 2) return file.Substring(0, i+1);
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Как проверить

```
Console.WriteLine(GetPrefix("FI_FILE1_111_1111"));
```

Результат

```
FI_FILE1_
```

Answer (score 4):

Еще вариант на Linq:

```
string s = "FI_FILE1_111_1111";
Console.WriteLine(
    Enumerable.Range(1, s.Length)
              .Select(x => s.Substring(0, x))
              .SkipWhile(ss => ss.Count(c => c == '_') != 2)
              .FirstOrDefault());
```

Берем входную строку, начинаем отрезать от начала один символ, потом два, потом три и т.д., пока не получится строка содержащая ровно два символа `_`. Если в строке нету двух символов `_` — вернется `null`. Да, это дичайше неэффективно.

Comment: О мои глаза! :D Что вы пишете, тут же дети могут увидеть!

Comment: @tym32167, ну хоть что-то надо было запостить, не проходить же мимо такого вопроса ;)

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам ещё один вариант с LINQ.

```
var s = "FI_FILE1_111_1111";
int count = 0;
var part = new string(s.TakeWhile(c => count < 2 && (c != '_' || ++count > -1)).ToArray());
```

Не пытайтесь повторить это <s>дома</s> в production'е.